Blocked on an ipad set up with a different email not linked to Apple id
iPad that is set up with an email and the email is not connected to original Apple ID. I got blocked from messaging the iPad but it rings when I call and when I FaceTime. Does the calls and FaceTimes still go through if my messages are blocked?
